# Python: how to insert a statement before break in while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

For the following while loop that I am using in Python:

```
while True: 
    <do something>
    if <condition>: break
```

but I want it to do something before it exits out, like this:

```
while True: 
    <do something>
    if <condition>: 
    <do something> 
    then break
```

Is it possible? what's the syntax? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just putting more code in the `if` block before the `break` statement?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that `break` is some kind of extension to the `if` statement syntax, but it's just a statement that happens to be executed from the body of the `if` statement. There's no reason you can't execute some other code prior to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put the statements inside of the `if` block

```
while True: 
    <do something>
    if <condition>: 
        <do something> 
        break
```